# Custom function on model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a query like this:

```
$results = User::where('gender', 'male')
    ->get();
```

Is there a way that I can call a custom function on this query, like:

```
$results = User::where('gender', 'male')
    ->get()
    ->split();
```

Where `split()` would be the following function:

```
public function split() {
    return array_chunk($results->toArray(), 10);
}
```

How would I implement something like this? Where would the function go?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it with collections helper, like so:

```
->get()->chunk(10);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-chunk

Comment: What if I wanted a custom helper?

Comment: @user6383193 you can extend a `Collection` class, like so:

`class MyOwnHelpers extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`